# Simple LINQ question: "Local sequence cannot be used" error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am pretty new to LINQ, so I'm assuming I'm missing something simple. I have code that generates the following error: *local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL*

```
return (from x in db.CurrentTrackings
                where x.strLocation == BarCode ||
                (from b in ChildBranches where x.strLocation == b.BarCode select b).Count() > 0 ||
                (from c in PlantCustomers where x.strLocation == c.customer_str_id select c).Count() > 0
                select x).Count();
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification. It seems like this should work, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have subqueries of local sequences (e.g., `ChildBranches`) mixed in with a LINQ-to-SQL query (i.e., `db.CurrentTrackings`) since the LINQ-to-SQL provider doesn't support any translating the local queries to a SQL query. LINQ to SQL *does* support *Contains()* for local sequences, in which case it converts it to an `WHERE X IN (Y1, Y2, Yn)` statement:

```
 var barCodes = ChildBranches.Select(b=>b.BarCode);
 var customerIds = PlantCustomers.Select(c=>c.customer_str_id);

 return (from x in db.CurrentTrackings
         where x.strLocation == BarCode ||
               barCodes.Contains(x.strLocation) ||
               customerIds.Contains(x.strLocation)
         select x).Count();
```

Comment: This works great! Now my trouble is, I have so much data, and I have to call this query many times, so it's really slow.

Comment: Look at using a compiled query?

Answer (score 1):

LocalSequences cannot be translated to SQL except when you use Contains so your query probably wants to be

```
return (from x in db.CurrentTrackings
       where 
         x.strLocation == BarCode || 
         ChildBranches.Select(b=>b.BarCode).Contains(x.strLocation) ||
         PlantCustomers.Select(c=>c.customer_str_id).Contains(x.strLocation) 
        select x).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

The query generates an SQL statement that will be send to the SQL Server however the ChildBranches and PlantCustomers collections cannnot be passed to the SQL Server.